# Laravel error: Missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I keep getting this error

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
```

When ever any page loads and I'm logged in.

Here is what my nav looks like

```
@if(Auth::guest())
                <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
            @else
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user()->nickname }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('user.settings') }}">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            @endif
```

The problem I'm having is that the {{ route('user.profile') }} is not working??

When i hit the link is www.mydomain.com/User/SCRATK/profile is works fine but the page wont load becuase of this error??

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile] [URI: user/{nickname}/profile].
```

This is my routes file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BaseController@index']);

Route::group(['namespace' => 'User', 'prefix' => 'user'], function(){
    Route::get('{nickname}/settings', ['as' => 'user.settings', 'uses' => 'SettingsController@index']);
    Route::get('{nickname}/profile', ['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@index']);
});
});
```

Comment: I have got round it like this for now <a href="{{ url('user/' . Auth::user()->nickname . '/profile') }}">Profile</a>

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to pass the route parameters to the `route` method, for example:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('user.profile', $nickname) }}">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ route('user.settings', $nickname) }}">Settings</a></li>
```

It's because, both routes have a `{nickname}` in the route declaration. I've used `$nickname` for example but make sure you change the `$nickname` to appropriate value/variable, for example, it could be something like the following:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('user.settings', auth()->user()->nickname) }}">Settings</a></li>
```

Comment: Yeah I tryed <li><a href="{{ url('user/' . Auth::user()->nickname . '/settings') }}">Settings</a></li> And that worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive changed it to this now <a href="{{ route('user.profile', Auth::user()->nickname) }}">Profile</a>

Comment: Seems a bit like a bug, because still get the error even if the controller method you are routing to has a default parameter eg: public function profile($nickname = null){...}

Comment: In that case, the route declaration should also declare as optional, for example in route parameter placeholder:  `{nickname?}` and optional params should be placed last in route.

Answer (score 5):

this is because we do not pass id to route as we have passed variable {nickname} in route. It is not fetching that from view.

your should  href="{{ route('user.profile', $nickname) }} so it can send the variable to route.

Answer (score 2):

My Solution in laravel 5.2

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['votes.submit', $video->id],  'method' => 'POST']) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Votar
    </button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My Routes File (under middleware)

```
Route::post('votar/{id}', [
    'as' => 'votes.submit',
    'uses' => 'VotesController@submit'
]);

Route::delete('votar/{id}', [
    'as' => 'votes.destroy',
    'uses' => 'VotesController@destroy'
]);
```

Comment: This is nothing todo with this question? It's about displaying a profile not displaying and deleting votes

Answer (score -5):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BaseController@index']);

Route::group(['namespace' => 'User', 'prefix' => 'user'], function(){
    Route::get('{nickname}/settings', ['as' => 'user.settings', 'uses' => 'SettingsController@index']);
    Route::get('{nickname}/profile', ['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@index']);
});
});
```