# Passing variable with route parameter when form is submitted Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, url-routing

I have this in my form in the viewpage.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('test.route'), ['id' => $params_id] }}" method="POST" >
```

And this in the route.php:

```
Route::post('/testing/{{id}}',[
    'uses' => 'TestController@testMethod', 
    'as' => 'test.route'
]);
```

And this is my TestController:

```
public function avaliarSubordinor(Request $request, $uid){
    return $uid;
}
```

I get an error which says 'Missing required parameters for[Route: test.route] [URI: testing/{{id}}]. Essentially What i want is to pass a variable to my controller using a route with a parameter when form is submitted..

I dont know if I am doing this properlly..if anyone can help me or point me to an example so i can understand what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 7):

[Laravel 5.2 Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile] [URI: user/{nickname}/profile]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259948/laravel-5-2-missing-required-parameters-for-route-user-profile-uri-user-ni)

Using the above link I found a solution.. I changed:

```
<form action="{{ route('test.route'), ['id' => $params_id] }}" method="POST" >
```

to

```
<form action="{{ route('test.route', [$params_id]) }}" method="GET" >
```

and this:

```
Route::post('/testing/{{id}}',[
     'uses' => 'TestController@testMethod', 
     'as' => 'test.route'
]);
```

to

```
Route::get('/testing/{id}',[
     'uses' => 'TestController@testMethod', 
     'as' => 'test.route'
]);
```

and for reading value :

```
if ($request->id) {
}
```

And It works! But I wonder if anyone else can get a POST version working, or is GET the only way? I dont really know much about GET/POST request, only that it's used in forms and ajax.. Would really like to learn more about HTTP GET/POST, if anyone has anything to add please share!! thanks! Hope this answer will help someone!

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked pretty well.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('user.show', $user->id))) }}
```

with class name

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('user.show', $user->id), 'class' => 'section-top')) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it's an old post hopefully it will help others in future. 
For me in **Laravel 5.8** the **POST** method just worked fine.

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" role="form" action="{{route('store_changed_role', [$user_id, $division_id])}}">
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/sotre_changed_role/{user_id}/{division_id}', 'Admin\UserController@store_changed_role')->name('store_changed_role');
```