# Missing required parameters in route Laravel 5.7

Tags: routes, laravel-5.7

what could be wrong with this:

route

```
Route::get('admin/view-news/{id}', 'AdminNewsController@show')->name('admin.view-news');
```

controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $news = News::all();
        return view('admin.news.news');
    }

public function show($id)
    {
        $news = News::Find($id);
        return view('admin.news.view_news')->with('news', $news);
```

in controller i tried this as well:

```
    `return view('admin.news.view_news', ['news' => News::findOrFail($id)])`;
```

view

{{ route ('admin.view-news') }}

An important note is, almost the same thing for users is working:

route:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UsersController@show');
```

controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(30);

        return view('admin.users.users')->with('users', $users);
    }


 public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        return view('admin.users.view_user')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

The error is:

**Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.view-news] [URI: admin/view-news/{id}].**

What am i missing here, how im not getting the id, and in users controller i do, with almost the same code? Thanks.

Comment: In your view `{{ route ('admin.view-news',$news->id) }}` you should provide the some id to route

Comment: or compare it with user view

Comment: i did, News:find($id) is not working for some reason, while User::find($id) does work, in show function in both controllers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 Missing required parameters for \[Route: user.profile\] \[URI: user/{nickname}/profile\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259948/laravel-5-2-missing-required-parameters-for-route-user-profile-uri-user-ni)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
{{ route('admin.view-news', $id) }}
```

Instead of

```
{{ route('admin.view-news') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Route::get('admin/view-news/{id?}', 'AdminNewsController@show')->name('admin.view-news');
```

for the view:

```
{{ route ('admin.view-news', ['id'=> $id ]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution:
In your blade file do like this

```
<a href="{{route('admin.view-news',"$id")}}">
  View
</a>
```

with this route , in route file

```
Route::get('admin/view-news/{id}', 'AdminNewsController@show');
```

$id is sent form your controller with compact

```
return view('viewPage', compact('id'));
```