# Missing required parameters for [Route: bill] [URI: bill/{id}]

Tags: php, html, laravel

I don't understand where the error is, here is my controller:

```
public function editBill(Request $req)
{
    $customerInfo=Customer::where('id',$req->id)->first();
    $billInfo=Bill::where('id',$req->id)->get();

    return view('admin.editBill', compact('customerInfo','billInfo'));
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('bill/{id}',[
    'as'=>'bill',
    'uses'=>'PageController@editBill'
]);
```

My blade:

```
 @foreach($i as $p)
                        <tr class="odd gradeX" align="center">
                            <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->id_customer}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->product}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->date_order}}</td>
                            <td>{{number_format($p->total)}} đ</td>
                            <td>{{$p->payment}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->note}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <!-- <td><a href="{{route('bill')}}/{{$p->id}}">Detail</a></td> -->
                            <td><a href="{{route('bill',$i->id)}}">Detail</a></td>
                            
                          
                        </tr>
                     @endforeach
```

There's the problem when I direct to Detail
Please help me, thanks

Comment: `{{route('bill',$i->id)}}` should most likely be `{{route('bill',$p->id)}}`

Comment: @brombeer comment / answer looks pretty good. but do you have any error message written in your logs?

Comment: well it's still not working. full errors is "Missing required parameters for [Route: bill] [URI: bill/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AppLaravel\resources\views\admin\orders.blade.php)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel error: Missing required parameters for route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259948/laravel-error-missing-required-parameters-for-route)

Comment: what version of Laravel?

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined route name but you are using url . So for passing parameter you will have to use ***url*** instead of route.

```
@foreach($i as $p)
                        <tr class="odd gradeX" align="center">
                            <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->id_customer}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->product}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->date_order}}</td>
                            <td>{{number_format($p->total)}} đ</td>
                            <td>{{$p->payment}}</td>
                            <td>{{$p->note}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <!-- <td><a href="{{route('bill')}}/{{$p->id}}">Detail</a></td> -->
                            <td><a href="{{ url('bill/'.$p->id)}}">Detail</a></td>
                            
                          
                        </tr>
                     @endforeach
```

Comment: I keep getting that error when I go to that orders.blade.php, but I succeed when I go to the Detail page when I address it